# Angular clear lazyload service providers when route changed

Tags: angular

I have a lazyload module A which contains several components and it also has a service that is provided inside my A module and is injected inside my components now I want to destroy my service instance whenever the route changes and the user goes into another module all of the components are destroyed but ngOnDestory on service not called.
I find out that after a lazyloaded module is loaded angular never destroys it the only option is to provide the service inside components however I want to share this service between all of the module components.
so is there a way to share service between module components and also destroy it when module changed?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution to my question if the lazyloaded module contains a root component with router-outlet for child components and all of the module services provided inside the root component instead of module all services then all services will be shared across module compoenents and when the user goes in another module all services will be destroyed as I wish.
Here is the router config

```
{
    path: '',
// Provide services inside this component
    component: RootComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ChildComponent1,
      },
      {
        path: 'a',
        component: ChildComponent2,
      }, {
        path: 'b',
        component: ChildComponent3,
  
      },
    ]
}
```